# Target unreachable CDI

Tags: jsf, jboss, cdi

I try to connect my web application with CDI but it don't want to work... There is an beans.xml file in `WEB-INF`. When I try to access fields from the CDI-Bean I get an `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException`

index.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:head>
    <title>Simple JSF Facelets page</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
            <h:form >

                <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Username: "/>
                    <p:inputText id="username" value="#{credentials.username}" />
                </p:panelGrid>
                <p:commandButton value="Login" action="#{credentials.login}" />
            </h:form>
</h:body>

</html>
```

Credentials.java

```
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;


@Named
@RequestScoped
public class Credentials{

    private String username;
    private String password;



    @Inject
    AuthController authController;

    public String login(){
        authController.authenticate(username);
        return "start";
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {

        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

AuthController.java

```
import addressbook.baselibs.enterprise.stereotype.Current;
import addressbook.user.entity.User;
import addressbook.user.repository.UserRepository;

import javax.enterprise.context.Conversation;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class AuthController implements Serializable{

    @Inject
    private Authentication authentication;

    @Inject
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Inject
    private FacesContext facesContext;

    @Inject
    private Conversation conversation;

    @Produces
    @Named
    @Current
    public User getCurrentUser() {
        return authentication.getCurrentUser();
    }

    public void authenticate(String username) {
        if(isLogged()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("User is logged and tries to authenticate again");
        }

        User user = userRepository.getForUserName(username);
        if(user == null) {
            // User not Found
        }

        authentication.setCurrentUser(user);
        conversation.begin();
    }

    public void logout() {
        authentication.setCurrentUser(null);
        conversation.end();
    }

    public boolean isLogged() {
        return authentication.getCurrentUser() != null;
    }

}
```

Stacktrace

```
00:58:49,975 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) /index.xhtml @15,86 value="#{credentials.username}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'credentials' resolved to null: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @15,86 value="#{credentials.username}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'credentials' resolved to null
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:100) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.getConverter(InputRenderer.java:154) [primefaces-3.1.1.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.getConvertedValue(InputRenderer.java:167) [primefaces-3.1.1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1030) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:960) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1233) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:698) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.primefaces.component.layout.Layout.processValidators(Layout.java:245) [primefaces-3.1.1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1172) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
```

Comment: please give AuthController  code

Comment: I added the AuthController source code

Comment: What app server are you using?

Comment: As you see he is using AS 7.1.1.
See: org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]

Comment: You have an injection point for FacesContext.  Do you have a producer for this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are injecting "conversation" scoped component in AuthController (private Conversation conversation)... Conversation scoped component is processed by Seam if 
    @Inject is used to perform injection after the RESTORE_VIEW phase..So during the "RESTORE_VIEW" phase this CONVERSATION scoped component will not be able to be instantiated and throws up
this error...Can you try to use 
    Component.getInstance() instead of 
    @inject for this conversation component and see if it helped resolved the issue?

Comment: Conversation here is the standard CDI conversation object.